# Windows App crashing at start, when build not created on same machine

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Im working on a windows 8.1 store app project, when i create a App package and install it on the same machine it works well, if i then use that package on a diferent machine, i get a crash at splash screen

**Machine 1**: PC with windows 10, developer mode activatedmm With visual studio 2015 installed

**Machine 2**: Surface with windows 8.1, With visual studio 2015 installed

On the tablet logs i see 2 errors
first one is:

> Event id 5973
>
> Activation of app app_03ym3vjwssmsm!App failed with
> error: The remote procedure call failed. See the
> Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

and the second one:

> Faulting application name: myapp.exe, version: 1.0.0.4, time stamp:
> 0x563a19ef
> Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll,
> version:6.3.9600.17904, time stamp: 0x557b0ffa Exception code:
> 0xc000027b Fault offset: 0x00000000009829ea
>
> Faulting process id: 0xad8 Faulting application start time:
> 0x01d11754e5d0b115
>
> Faulting application path: C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\app_1.1.0.25_x64__03ym3vjwssmsm\myapp.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll Report
> Id: 23b679c5-8348-11e5-be73-6045bde98157
>
> Faulting package full name: app_1.1.0.25_x64__03ym3vjwssmsm Faulting
> package-relative application ID: App

Also, both machines run on x64 , and i build my package as x64.

I use a test certificate.

Do i need to something extra for my package to run on other machines?

**EDIT**

If i create app package on **Machine 1**, and install on **Machine 1** - Works

If i create app package on **Machine 2**, and install on **Machine 2** - Works

If i create app package on **Machine 1**, and install on **Machine 2** - fails

If i create app package on **Machine 2**, and install on **Machine 1** - fails

Comment: In Windows 10, you need to [enable developer mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn726766.aspx) on the PC, if it is Windows 8/8.1, you need to [acquire a developer license](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj657534(v=wps.630).aspx). Finally, you need to actually [install the app package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/hh975356.aspx)

Comment: Are they both running the same Windows build, and does that match the SDK build you used? This matters more if you're in the Insiders Program.

Comment: In the windows 10 machine i have dev mode enabled

Comment: i've added a bit more information on my post

Comment: The error code 5973 sometimes points to a profile corruption. There are a number of web sites that have suggested and potential workarounds that you may want to try.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3064045